# Writing hex to a file

Tags: c++, string, file, hex

I have a program that reads the `hex` of a file, modifies it, and stores the modified hex in a `std::string`.

For example, how would I write this to a file

```cpp
std::string wut="b6306edf953a6ac8d17d70bda3e93f2a3816eac333d1ac78";
```

and get its value

```
.0n..:j..}p...?*8...3..x
```

in the outputted file?

I'd prefer not to use `sprintf`, but I guess if it's necessary, I'll do what I must.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "_hex of a file_"? You're thinking about the binary, unformatted content of the file, or a single hexadecimal value?

Comment: The content, all converted to hex. I'm new to this field of knowledge, so...

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are reading in a binary file, storing the data as a hex string, and then want to write the the modified data back to the file (in binary)?

Comment: Define binary file. In all honesty, it is not a specifically formatted file; so in a sense, yes.

Comment: Binary file means "not a text file." All files are binary, but a text file means that the contents are to be interpreted as printable text data.

Comment: Then yes, a binary file. :)

Comment: You would do well to explain (and show) how the file is *read*, and how it is translated to a hexadecimal string. If you don't know how that is done, read the code. It sounds like you need a hexidecimal string to binary octet converter and if so, search for "[c++] convert hex string to binary". Then write the resulting blob to the file using a binary-mode output stream.

Comment: @Peter R's answer seems to do the trick. But I'm going to continue looking into what you all have said and learn all I can. Thank you all for your help! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want the text converted to it's numeric equivalent and then written to file. Given the hint you provided in your question it looks like this should be done byte by byte. Below is one way to achieve this. Note the need to convert each byte from a string to an integer value.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ios>

std::string wut = "b6306edf953a6ac8d17d70bda3e93f2a3816eac333d1ac78";

int main()
{
    std::ofstream datafile("c:\\temp\\temp1.dat", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::out);

    char buf[3];
    buf[2] = 0;

    std::stringstream input(wut);
    input.flags(std::ios_base::hex);
    while (input)
    {
        input >> buf[0] >> buf[1];
        long val = strtol(buf, nullptr, 16);
        datafile << static_cast<unsigned char>(val & 0xff);
    }

}
```

Comment: BE CAREFUL! This does not work if there are zeros in the hex string in a chain of two or more '0's in a row!

see another possible solution I provided below, which will work in 100% times, assuming the hex string is of even length.

Comment: Notice: the last byte added an extra zero so file corrupted!

Answer (score 3):

The answer of @Peter R will lead to an output which is not 100% equal, due to the `stringstream` interpreting more than one '0's in a row in an unintended way.

*Example*: If we want to write the hex value "00000000", the `stringstream` would output " 000000".

The solution below works in every case, **no matter how many zeros are contained in the hex string**:

```cpp
// Input
std::string hex = "180f00005e2c3415"; // (or longer)

std::basic_string<uint8_t> bytes;

// Iterate over every pair of hex values in the input string (e.g. "18", "0f", ...)
for (size_t i = 0; i < hex.length(); i += 2)
{
    uint16_t byte;

    // Get current pair and store in nextbyte
    std::string nextbyte = hex.substr(i, 2);

    // Put the pair into an istringstream and stream it through std::hex for
    // conversion into an integer value.
    // This will calculate the byte value of your string-represented hex value.
    std::istringstream(nextbyte) >> std::hex >> byte;

    // As the stream above does not work with uint8 directly,
    // we have to cast it now.
    // As every pair can have a maximum value of "ff",
    // which is "11111111" (8 bits), we will not lose any information during this cast.
    // This line adds the current byte value to our final byte "array".
    bytes.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(byte));
}

// we are now generating a string obj from our bytes-"array"
// this string object contains the non-human-readable binary byte values
// therefore, simply reading it would yield a String like ".0n..:j..}p...?*8...3..x"
// however, this is very useful to output it directly into a binary file like shown below
std::string result(begin(bytes), end(bytes));
```

Then you can simply write this string to a file like this:

```cpp
std::ofstream output_file("filename", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
if (output_file.is_open())
{
    output_file << result;
    output_file.close();
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Error could not create file." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: it worked fine, would you mind explaining the logic a bit?

Comment: @DanielSelvan added comments