# How to read '00' hex byte from binary file?

Tags: c++, stl, binaryfiles, ifstream, ofstream

I have a function, which saves hex string into a binary file.

```
void save_in_binary(std::string& str, std::ofstream& outfile) {
    char buf[3];
    buf[2] = 0;

    std::stringstream input(str);
    input.flags(std::ios_base::hex);
    while (input >> buf[0] >> buf[1]) {
        long val = strtol(buf, nullptr, 16);
        outfile << static_cast<unsigned char>(val & 0xff);
    }
}
```

And the other, that reads it afterwards

```
int parse_binary_text(std::string& name, std::string& text) {
    std::ifstream myfile(name, std::ios::binary);

    unsigned int tmp = 0;         // flag
    std::stringstream input;
    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        while (!myfile.eof()) {
            tmp = myfile.get();
            if (tmp == UINT_MAX)
                break;
            input << std::hex << tmp;
        }
        text = input.str();
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

But upon saving hex string "0FFE00" i then read "FFE0". It seems like my read function skips zero-bytes. Debugging showed that when `tmp` (flagged in code) equals 0, `std::hex` writes nothing - that's the issue. So, this prompts my question: how do i fix this?

Comment: Don't use `while (input) `  as stop condition. Check for end of file instead.

Comment: @LouisGo, fixed it now, but, unfortunately, it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: "But upon saving hex string "0FE00" i then read "FFE0"" When you save that string, how many bytes long do you intend for the output file to be? What do you intend to be the numeric values of those bytes? Why? What string do you expect to get back out? It's not clear to me how you intend to convert an odd number of hex digits to bytes, given that exactly two such digits represent a byte.

Comment: Also: your intention in `void save_in_binary(std::string& str, std::ofstream& outfile) {` is that the `outfile` has been opened in binary mode, yes? What do you expect to happen when you use `operator<<` on such a file? Why? Are you familiar with the `.write` member function?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel. I converted binary to hex, then i saved hex bytes in a binary file. Next im trying to read those and convert them back into binary string. I opened the output file using hex editor, and it shows `0F FE 00` - that's the output im looking for (spacing is optional)

Comment: I'm confused - was your input string `"0FFE00"` (corresponding to what you're describing now), or `"0FE00"` (what you actually typed in the post)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, about `operator<<`. I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819782/writing-hex-to-a-file)

Comment: Printing numbers does not print leading zeros. If you print 15 (i.e. your first byte) as hexadecimal, you get "F", not "0F", and if you print zero, you get "0", not "00". Thus, your sequence `15, 254, 0` prints as "FFE0".

Answer (score -1):

I run the code,upon saving hex string "0FE00" i then read "FE0". Is it correct?

I modified `input << std::hex << tmp;` to `input <<std::setw(2)<<std::setfill('0') << std::hex << tmp;` to read "0FE0" .

Code:

```
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
void save_in_binary(std::string& str, std::ofstream& outfile) {
    char buf[3];
    buf[2] = 0;

    std::stringstream input(str);
    input.flags(std::ios_base::hex);
    while (input >> buf[0] >> buf[1]) {
        long val = strtol(buf, nullptr, 16);
        outfile << static_cast<unsigned char>(val & 0xff);
    }
}

int parse_binary_text(std::string& name, std::string& text) {
    std::ifstream myfile(name, std::ios::binary);

    unsigned int tmp = 0;
    std::stringstream input;
    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        while (input) {
            tmp = myfile.get();
            if (tmp == UINT_MAX)
                break;
            input <<std::setw(2)<<std::setfill('0') << std::hex << tmp;
        }
        text = input.str();
    }
    else
        return 0;
}


int main3(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::string str = "0FE00",name="test.txt",strget;
    std::ofstream ofs(name, std::ios::binary);
    save_in_binary(str, ofs);
    ofs.close();
    parse_binary_text(name, strget);
```

Comment: Tried your code, but somehow im not recieving "FE0". Nethertheless, the output should be "FE000", which is not equal to "FE0"

Comment: okay,i thought ```input <<std::setw(2)<<std::setfill('0')``` should fix,but didnot in your case